# Is Zalgo text in usernames OK?

Tags: discussion, users

I was looking at the badges page and noticed this in the sidebar:

[image]

Looking more closely, I discovered that these strange marks come from [this user](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/4928/%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98). Because they have a Zalgo-text username, it can often interfere with other text on the same page. E.g. on one of their questions:

[image]

---

**Is this enough of an issue that the moderators should step in and edit the Zalgo text out of this user's name?**

---

My personal feeling is that although this particular instance is fairly harmless in itself, allowing Zalgo text in usernames could set a dangerous precedent, as seen in [this case](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8152/whats-going-on-with-this-question) from another site.

Comment: This seems like a question probably better adressed at the main [meta.se].

Comment: @NapoleonWilson It'd probably get closed as a dupe or something. I preferred to keep it low-profile by just posting here (and even considered simply pinging you in TL rather than posting publicly).

Comment: Well, *if* there's already a duplicate on [meta.se], then even better, we'd already have an answer anyway. If this question is *solely* to notify the moderators, then simply flagging the user would be even more "low-profile". I mean, there's nothing wrong with this question, it's just that being a larger-scale SE issue would maybe get more insightful answers on the larger-scale meta site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247022/162011) on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and its answers using Zalgo text in usernames, while technically supported, is discouraged as it tends to break quite a few things, like you already noticed. **Users shall not use extensive Zalgo text in their usernames**. Doing so will have the moderators revert the username and notify the respective user.

Thanks for bringing this to notice.

Comment: Those answers point to names that break functionality as being bad. How did that user's name break functionality or be otherwise extensive?

Comment: @cde Just look at the question to see examples of how it breaks the user interface. Your username has nothing to do inside other names or the below comment section. What other disruptions do you want to see?